# Entry.get() gives error, different every time. Invalid command name .55

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, udp, chat

I am trying to make a simple chat window for school. When I try to use the entry.get() function it gives an error which changes every time I test the code.
Here is the script:

```
import socket
import sys
import tkinter

global ready
ready = False
def setready():
    global ready
    ready = True
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("MAGENTA Chat Host v1 - send")
window.geometry("200x100")
window.configure(bg = "magenta")
but = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Send", command = (setready()))
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, bg = "magenta", fg = "snow", text = "Chat")
msgfield = tkinter.Entry(window)
but.pack(side = tkinter.RIGHT)
lbl.pack(side = tkinter.TOP)
msgfield.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)
message = "Message"
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    lbl.config(text = "Socket successfully created")
except socket.error as err:
    lbl.config(text = "Socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))

window.mainloop()

while True:
    if ready == True:
        message = msgfield.get()
        if message == "exit":
            s.close()
            window.destroy()
            sys.exit()
        else:
            s.sendto(bytes(message, "utf-8"),(UDP_IP,5000))
            msgfield.select_clear()
            ready = False
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\qscguest\Desktop\ChatSend.py", line 33, in <module>
    message = msgfield.get()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2522, in get
    return self.tk.call(self._w, 'get')
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".55573472"
```

How did I mess up so badly? How do I fix this?

Comment: You have infinite recursion because inside `setready` you're doing `command=setready()`. Your function is calling itself. That's not what you want. You want to set `command` to the _function itself_, not to the return value of the function: `command=setready`.

Comment: nothing changed. same error.

Comment: The indentation of the code is incorrect, making it impossible to know what code is inside `setready` and what is not.

Comment: @BryanOakley True, I hadn't considered the possibility that the function ends right after `ready = True`. Still, `command=setready()` is incorrect, no matter what the real indentation is.

Comment: fixed that. now indented properly

Answer (score 0):

`window.mainloop()` won't exit until the root window is destroyed. Any code after that which tries to reference a widget will fail, since the widget has been destroyed.

Comment: I see what you mean, however where should I put it? if I put it at the end that will never work either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to have your tkinter app close the program when you type exit and hit send as well as do some other function if else. I have modified you code to do what I think you are attempting.

I changed a few thing.

One I got rid of the global as its not needed because we can move `ready` to a defined function for you while loop.

I changed the button to run the command `myWhile()` loop with lambda so myWhile is not called on startup.

I added a function called `myWhile()` to house the while loop and perform the task you needed done. Let me know if this is what you were looking for as I am not 100% sure on your needs.

```
import socket
import sys
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("MAGENTA Chat Host v1 - send")
window.geometry("200x100")
window.configure(bg = "magenta")
but = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Send", command = lambda: myWhile())
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, bg = "magenta", fg = "snow", text = "Chat")
msgfield = tkinter.Entry(window)
but.pack(side = tkinter.RIGHT)
lbl.pack(side = tkinter.TOP)
msgfield.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)
message = "Message"
UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    lbl.config(text = "Socket successfully created")
except socket.error as err:
    lbl.config(text = "Socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))


def myWhile():
    ready = True
    while ready == True:
        message = msgfield.get()
        print ('ready')
        if message == "exit":
            s.close()
            window.destroy()
            sys.exit()
        else:
            s.sendto(bytes(message, "utf-8"),(UDP_IP,5000))
            msgfield.select_clear()
            ready = False

window.mainloop()
```